# Fancybox modal window not automatically opening on page load

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've been through numerous posts in relation to this but I just can't get to the bottom of it.  I have a video on the home page of my website.  When a visitor clicks the play video graphic a YouTube video is played within a Fancybox modal.  I want to send an email newsletter encouraging subscribers to watch the video by clicking a link in the newsletter which takes them to my site and automatically launches the Fancybox modal playing the video.  However I cannot get this to work.  In my head tag I have:

```
<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$base_url}/assets/js/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.3"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$base_url}/assets/js/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.2" media="screen" />

<!-- Add Media helper (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$base_url}/assets/js/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.5"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#video-intro').fancybox({
      openEffect : 'none',
      closeEffect : 'none',
      prevEffect : 'none',
      nextEffect : 'none',
      arrows : false,
      width   : '640',
      height    : '360',
      helpers : {
        media : {}
        buttons : {}
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#video-intro").trigger('click');​
  });
 </script>
```

An in my body I have the following link:

```
<a id="video-intro" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Scd0dmAod-k?rel=0" onClick=”_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Video', 'Play', 'RentPro Overview Video']);”><img src="{$base_url}assets/img/play-video.png" width="425" height="239" alt="Click to play RentPro overview video" style="border:1px solid #fff;" /></a>
```

However I cannot get this to automatically display the modal and play the video on page load.  The actual href has an onClick event to register an event with Google Analytics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single script should be enough :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#video-intro').fancybox({
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        prevEffect: 'none',
        nextEffect: 'none',
        arrows: false,
        width: 640,
        height: 360,
        helpers: {
            media: {},
            buttons: {}
        },
        type: "iframe"
    }).trigger("click");
}); // ready
```

**NOTICE** that I corrected from your script the following:

- Integer values go **without** quotes
- There was a missing comma after `media : {}, //<-- comma here` to separate it from the following option `buttons: {}`
- I set the `.trigger("click")` to the same selector so no need of two different scripts
- Since you are using youtube's `embed` form, I added `type: "iframe"` to the API options

See it working in this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J6vZ3/)**

The analytics `onclick` shouldn't be an issue as you can see in the `console.log`

Comment: Thanks @JFK. That worked, but I was getting a problem with it running in Chrome which turned out to be an issue with the Google Analytics tracking code I was using.  Needed to update it to the latest version.

The reason I had this in two set of scripts was that I didn't want it auto opening all the time but only on www.example.com?autoplay=true for example.  I used your version of the script with all in one call and if the query string parameter autoplay was true used it otherwise used the original code. Just out of interest any idea why this wouldn't work when it was loaded as two scripts?